# What is the best way to implement this Python code

Tags: python, if-statement, design-patterns

I have this simple code here:

```
def myFunction(a: my_enumA, b: my_enumB, c: my_enumC):
  
  if a:
    update_a = update_from_db_a(a=a)
  else:
    update_a = True
  
  if b:
    update_b = update_from_db_b(b=b)
  else:
    update_b = True
  
  if c:
    update_c = update_from_db_c(c=c)
  else:
    update_c = True
    
  if update_a and update_b and update_c:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

I'm sure that a design patern exists for this but I don't know the name.

What is the best way Pythonic way to implement it ? Maybe with a design pattern?

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to just returning `not(a or b or c)` ? What do the `update_from_db_X` return ?

Comment: I question the need for this kind of wrapper function in the first place. Let the caller decide whether the appropriate update functions need to be called, then pass a list like `[update_from_db_a(v1), True, update_from_db_c(v3)]` to `all`.

Comment: That was my first idea. update_from_db must be done to save some data in the database. 
In your example, if b is false, it won't try to save the data for c.

Comment: The function update make a query to save some data and return Trueif it works or False if it does not work

Answer (score 3):

You could transform each of your first `if`s into a single statement:

```
# If a is False, value is True
# If a is True, value is update_from_db_a(a=a)
update_a = not a or update_from_db_a(a=a)
```

Notice that if `not a` is `True` (a.k.a `a` is `False`) it won't execute the next part of the condition (it won't call `update_from_db_a`).

Also, your function will return `True` only if a condition is True, so you could re-write it like this:

```
# If condition is True, returns True
# If condition is False, returns False
return update_a and update_b and update_c
```

---

Resulting code:

```
def myFunction(a: my_enumA, b: my_enumB, c: my_enumC):
    update_a = not a or update_from_db_a(a=a)
    update_b = not b or update_from_db_b(b=b)
    update_c = not c or update_from_db_c(c=c)
    return update_a and update_b and update_c
```

Comment: "Also, your function will return True only if a condition is True, so you could re-write it like this:" No I can't. I need to go to update_from_db_a, if a = True  but also if 
in update_from_db_b if b = true

Answer (score 1):

You can compress all conditions and pass them to `all()`:

```py
def myFunction(a: my_enumA, b: my_enumB, c: my_enumC):
    return all([
        not a or update_from_db_a(a=a),
        not b or update_from_db_b(b=b),
        not c or update_from_db_c(c=c)
    ])
```

Be sure to wrap them in an iterable, such as a `list`, `tuple` or `set`, and not in a generator. Otherwise `all()` will terminate on the first false condition.

Comment: Why a `set` in particular? I think a `tuple` or `list` would do the job too. The important part is to avoid using a generator right?

Comment: Right. I chose a set out of habit, because on large sets of conditions it only stores one instance of `True` or `False` and might accelerate `all()`. But you can also use a `tuple` or a `list`.